# The Amazing audio engine 2 - Crossfade looping

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, cross-fade, the-amazing-audio-engine

I am using [the amazing audio engine 2](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine2) library for my sequencer app and I want to implement Crossfade loop audio.

Here is explanation :

When user press any key in sequencer piano it will play some audio file and and that audio file will continue to play in loop until user release the key. But that loop will be crossfade to itself.

I am using **AEAudioFilePlayerModule** for looping but not sure how to crossfade audio file with this class.

**Explanation of Cross fade :**

[image]

**Start/End**: This setting allows me to choose where in the audio file I want the app to constantly loop so that if user taps+holds note down for a long time, the audio will sound continuously until the user releases his finger.

**XFade**: This function (crossfade) allows me to chose how to fade between the end and start of the audio loop. This is good so
that the sound will loop smoothly. Here, 9999 is set. So at about 5k samples before the 200k end point, the audio for this note
will begin to fade away and at the same time, the audio loop starting at 50k samples will fade in for a duration of about 5k samples (1/2 the XFade amount).

Please help.

Thank you.